# expect script cutting/trunking lines

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, expect

I'm running a script that connects to some unix servers and grabs a list of information, however I see that some parts of the information collected are getting cut/truncated by the spawn command:

for example:

```
U2107.D02.RJ02DBH-P1-D20         7  node2     RJ02DBH 1          544C01        active U2107.D02 
U2107.D02.RJ02DBH-P1-D20         1  node1     RJ02DBH 2          558B01        active U2107.D02              
U2107.D02.RJ02DBH-P1-D20         7  node2     RJ02DBH 2          554C02        active U2107.D02              
spawn sh lscardscript.sh      1  node1      RJ0
The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:i0CmsCsxkjdsahjdajhdsajhfhxxxxiAg.
```

In the example above, the text `spawn sh lscardscript.sh` shouldn't be there, and is causing a line to be truncated. Then the script tries to connect to the next IP and sometimes the lines got truncated on the next one, sometimes not.

Here is my code:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<'END_EXPECT'

    set timeout -1
    sleep 1
    send \r
    spawn sh lscardscript.sh
    expect "yes" { send "yes\r"}
    expect {
        -nocase "*assword*" {
            send "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        eof
    }
```

I've tried many things already but still seeing the same behavior, does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Your posted code runs `sh lscardscript.sh` without any arguments. There's nothing to truncate...

Answer (score 1):

Your command `send \r` (CR = carriage return) asks the "output cursor" to go back to the beginning of the line. That is why the text "spawn sh lscardscript.sh" overwrites the last output line.

You should probably send `\n` instead (LF = line feed), or `\r\n`. `\n` will cause the "output cursor" to go to the next line, which will preserve the text that is already written.

Of course, this `\n` must not interfere with what the other side expects to receive, but we do not know anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue... I added the following line to my script. So it will run the command I need, grabs the output and wait 2 seconds before calls the next command.

```
echo "sleep 2" >> lscardscript.sh
```